# Como mudar o titulo do blog wordpress direto no php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estou na fase final do desenvolvimento do meu blog no `wordpress` e há alguns meses atrás, quando comecei a desenvolver coloquei um `título`, mas depois de muitas pesquisas resolvi muda-lo, pois encontrei outro parecido - quero que o meu seja único - então resolvi colocar outro título.

**Quero mudar o título que fica logo do lado do favicon, ou seja, a tag `<title>`**

Inicialmente mudei no `Painel de Configurações / Geral / Título do Site`

No painel mostra que mudou, mas quando aperto `F5`, continua com o título anterior.

- Excluí histórico do navegador também por causa do `cache`, mas não adiantou.
- Testei no `Firefox`, agora estou testando no `Chrome`, mas o título permanece o mesmo.
- Tentei procurar no arquivo `themes / o meu tema / header.php` a tag `<title>`, mas não há tal tag no meu `header`.
- Tentei escrever um `title` para sobrescrever o que já existe, mas também não funcionou.

Procurei no `index`, mas o `index` chama o `header`.

Alguém sabe onde mais posso encontrar o `title` no `php` do `wordpress` para mudar? Porque no `painel` não está mudando mesmo.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Inicialmente cuidado na montagem da dúvida, uma pergunta mal formatada pode mudar o objetivo e assim fazer com que sua pergunta não seja respondida. No post você cita ter tentado encontrar a tag `header`, não quis falar `head`? Pois `header` é uma tag destinada a um cabeçalho, como o topo do site, e `head` contem as informações da página, como o `title` então certifique-se que tenha pesquisado na tag correta.

Comment: Entendi. Então, eu procurei o header.php mesmo, para depois procurar a tag head dentro da pagina header.php. Porque a tag head era para estar dentro do index, entrei no index e o index estava "chamando" pela pagina header.php. Dentro da pagina header.php deveria estar a tag head com o titulo dentro. Mas não tem o titulo, só a tag.

Comment: Marcielli, dá uma olhada na edição que fiz na minha resposta.

Comment: @Chun Acabei de arrumar e era isso mesmo. Muito Obrigada. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não deves ter encontrado a tag `<title>` no `header.php` porque provavelmente esta deve estar a ser implementada através do [`<?php wp_head(); ?>`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

Se pesquisares no ficheiro `header.php` dentro da tag `<head>`, muito provavelmente deverás encontrar esta sintax - `<?php wp_head(); ?>`, que é uma função implementada no `functions.php` responsável por implementar o `<title>`, `<style>` etc.

Se for este o caso, para mudar o título basta ires a:

```
Dashboard => Settings => General => Site Title
```

Muda o **site title** para o novo nome que queres para o site.

---

### Edição

Como estás a utilizar um **Plugin de Cache** e de **SEO** (All in One SEO Pack), também tens que fazer as alterações do novo título no plugin de SEO e resetar/eliminar o cache do Plugin de Cache.

Para fazer as mudanças do título no Plugin de SEO, navega até:

```
All in One SEO Pack => General Settings => Home Page Settings => Home Title:
```

ou acessando o link: `http://meusite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=all-in-one-seo-pack%2Faioseop_class.php%2F#aiosp_home_metabox` e altera o título do `Home Title:` para o novo título que queres definir. A utilização deste plugin vai substituir o título do site (`<title>`), pelo texto/título que definires aqui.

> (Eu testei isto pessoalmente).

E de seguida precisas de eliminar ou resetar o cache do Plugin de Cache, para que as atualizações sejam aplicadas.

Comment: É esse o caso sim, encontrei dentro da página header.php essa função. Porém, eu tentei mudar pelo Dashboard => Settings => General => Site Title, no painel mostra que eu mudei de um para outro, porém quando atualizo a pagina, é como se eu não tivesse mudado nas configurações. Dai eu volto nas configurações, e o novo title está lá.

Comment: Qual é o tema que estás a usar?

Comment: Estou usando o Oblique. Segue o link: https://wordpress.org/themes/oblique/

Comment: Comentei essa sintax <?php wp_head(); ?> e coloquei <title>Nome do site</title> mas do mesmo jeito quando dei f5 apareceu o nome antigo, mesmo eu tendo colocado o nome novo no title da sintax.

Comment: Mesmo ao comentar o título continua? Antes de atualizar tente limpar os cookies e cache do navegador pressionando `Ctrl + Shift + Delete`

Comment: Sim, anteriormente eu tinha apagado só o cache, mas agora fiz como você disse e apaguei os cookies também. Não adiantou.

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Então, quando eu comentei essa sintax <?php wp_head(); ?>, eu coloquei o <title>Nome do site</title> com outro nome, e o titulo anterior continuou. Quando eu apenas comento, e não coloco um title com outro nome, ele aparece apenas localhost/wordpress

Comment: tem instalado algum plugin de cache no WordPress? experimentou deletar o cache do plugin e também atualizar a página usando: `Ctrl+F5` ou `Ctrl+Shift+F5`. Tem instalado algum plugin de SEO para meta tags?

Comment: Já tentei atualizar  a página desse modo. Tenho instalado o plugin All in One SEO Pack, até no começo achei que fosse ele, pois quando criei a página inicial, logo abaixo pede o Titulo do SEO, mas editei a página e nela está um titulo diferente, então nisso eu sei que não é. Então, talvez possa ser a tag, como você disse...Vou procurar. E Sobre o plugin do Cache, tenho um. Vou procurar essa opção nele, pois não encontrei ainda. Obrigada pela atenção. ;)

Comment: @MarcielliOliveira poderia alterar a linha `<?php wp_head(); ?>` para `<?php var_dump(wp_head()); ?>`? Ao atualizar a página ele deve escrever um código no topo do blog, assim você poderia enviar o código para a gente, e fica mais fácil detectar o erro.

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Sim, fiz isso e apareceu NULL.

Comment: Muito estranho, segundo a documentação do wordpress a função `wp_head` deveria retornar parte do `head` da página. Mas fuçando na documentação encontrei também a `wp_title` que retorna o título do blog, e em um exemplo da própria documentação, você pode colocar `<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>` para trocar o título, se não funcionar colocando após o `<?php wp_head(); ?>`  tente apagar a linha e tentar apenas com o `wp_title`

Comment: Muito estranho mesmo. Tentei colocar depois do wp_head e não houve mudança. Então, coloquei apenas o <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title> e desconfigurou toda a página. Vou continuar procurando e se encontrar alguma coisa, posto aqui. Obrigada pela atenção @LeonardoVIlarinho

Comment: @Chun Muito Obrigada, era exatamente isso! Acabei de arrumar aqui. Esse é meu primeiro blog, estou aprendendo ainda. Uma coisa tão simples de se arrumar e sem a sua ajuda com certeza eu ficaria ainda um bom tempo tentando resolver... rs Obrigada mesmo! ;)